# QTableWidget not displaying data from SetItem, both row and column count are set

Tags: c++, qt

Probably a simple mistake however i havent come across any similar posts. Im trying to display a CSV file in a QTableWidget however when i run my code nothing is displayed. ive verified im reading all of the data and i can grab the data from the QTableWidget, However nothing is displayed on screen.
A simplified version of the code:

```
ui->MyQTableWidget->setRowCount(100);
ui->MyQTableWidget->setColumnCount(7);
QFile active(filepath);
    active.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    if (!active.isOpen())
        return;
    int line = 0;
    QTextStream in(&active);
    while(!in.atEnd()){
        QString Line = in.readLine();
        QStringList LinePart = Line.split(",", Qt::SkipEmptyParts);
        for(int j = 0; j < LinePart.size(); j++){
            QTableWidgetItem item(LinePart.at(j));
            ui->MyQTableWidget->setItem(line, j, &item);
        }
        line++;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `QTableWidgetItem item(LinePart.at(j));` - c++ basics - how long does this object lives?

Comment: Eesh, ive taught classes on c before. Yeah i fixed it by changing it to ui->MyQTableWidget->setItem(line, j, new QTableWidgetItem(LinePart.at(j)));

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but we know nothing about you, and we can only base our assumptions on your question and its code. "nothing is displayed on screen" is *extremely* ambiguous: is the table shown? If it is, are you *completely* sure that the shown table *is* `MyQTableWidget`? Because if you're able to access the QTableWidget data and "nothing" is shown, then we clearly need some further details about your environment, code, build system, etc. So, please, humor us and provide a proper [mre].

Comment: you misunderstood me, i was saying you were right and eesh i should know this. apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve it by changing it to the following:

```
ui->MyQTableWidget->setItem(line, j, new QTableWidgetItem(LinePart.at(j)))
```